# Why is this SQL Update failing ("column name is not valid")?

Tags: sql, sql-update, sql-server-ce

I've got a SQL Server CE table like so:

[image]

...and I'm trying to update its solitary record like so:

```
update workTables 
set fileType = "INV"
```

Yet I get:

[image]

Why?

### UPDATE

Please see a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25314898/why-is-this-sql-update-failing-with-there-was-an-error-parsing-the-query)

Comment: have you tried quoting in case tablename or columnname are reserved words?  update [workTables] set [fileType] = 'INV'  (note single quotes around INV  Also make sure you are pointing at the correct database

Comment: I'll try that tomorrow - they kick us out at 5; single or double quotes, or does it matter?

Comment: Yes, it does matter. Mitch Wheat is right, you have to use single quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query should be:

```
   update [workTables] 
   set [fileType] = 'INV' 

Note: single quotes ^^^^
```

Answer (score 2):

Here check Microsoft support for yor error.
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/825392

This is from the site:

```
SYMPTOMS:

When you run a query on a Microsoft SQL Server 2000 Windows CE Edition version 2.0 database, and the query has a column that contains one or more space characters, the query may not be successful. Additionally, you may receive the following error message:
FAILED: select <Column Name> from <Table Name>
Error: 0x80040e14 DB_E_ERRORSINCOMMAND
Native Error: (25503)
Description: The column name is not valid. [,,,Node name (if any),Column name,]
Interface defining error: IID_ICommand
Param. 0: 0
Param. 1: 0
Param. 2: 0
Param. 3:
Param. 4: col1
Param. 5:

RESOLUTION:
To resolve this problem, enclose the column name that contains spaces in quotation marks (" "), and then run the query. For example, you can run the following query, and the query results are displayed successfully:
SELECT "col1 " FROM testtable
```