# Why is this SQL update failing with "there was an error parsing the query"?

Tags: sql, sql-update, sql-server-ce

An earlier problem with this query was resolved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25298045/why-is-this-sql-update-failing-column-name-is-not-valid) but now this query:

[image]

...fails with:

[image]

Why? It worked once (it was the fix for the earlier question linked to above).

The unseen part of the err msg's "Description" line is: "*[Token line number,Token line offset,,Token in error,,]*"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strangely enough, removing the brackets surrounding the table name and column name allowed the update to fire successfully.

So why it worked once before, I don't grok.