# Why do my "safety brackets" actually PREVENT this SQL from Working?

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce, brackets, dml, square-bracket

I've got some code that had previously apparently needed to have brackets applied to a SQL statement due to a column named "Name"; the "fixed" code was:

```
dynSQL = string.Format("DELETE FROM Platypi WHERE duckbill = '{0}' and [Name] = '{1}'", tmpType, tmpStr);
```

Unfortunately, this code was not doing its job - the record was not being deleted. Removing the brackets around the "Name" column:

```
dynSQL = string.Format("DELETE FROM Platypi WHERE duckbill = '{0}' and Name = '{1}'", tmpType, tmpStr);
```

...caused it to work. Why would adding the "suspenders" to the column name cause the column to be unrecognized? An answer to a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25298045/why-is-this-sql-update-failing-column-name-is-not-valid) indicates that encasing column names (and table names) in brackets is a safe way to avoid naming collisions with other objects/database keywords and such.

When the SQL with the brackets fails, no err msg is displayed, it just doesn't work.

Note, though, that this is inconsistent; sometimes the SQL which contains the "[Name]" as opposed to "Name" works fine - IOW, sometimes the same SQL statement with the same val for "duckbill" but a different one for "Name" works; with "valerie" it fails (when the column named "Name" is bracketed).

Comment: I could imagine that this might have to do with the case of the identifier.  This wouldn't normally happen in SQL Server.  SQL Server CE is different in various ways, and I could imagine that certain internationalization setting code have the effect you are seeing.

Comment: could you echo the contents of dynSQL?

Comment: @ludwigmace: "DELETE FROM Platypi WHERE duckbill = 'INV' and [Name] = 'valerie'" vs. "DELETE FROM Platypi WHERE duckbill = 'INV' and Name = 'valerie'"
First one fails, second one succeeds.

Comment: That's really weird.  Since it's weird, have you tried throwing some unnecessary parentheses around each clause, or a semicolon at the end?  I'd do it but I don't have Visual Studio/SQLCE where I am.

Comment: @ludwigmace: What would a semicolon possibly do? What purpose is it supposed to serve?

Comment: Since SQLCE isn't necessarily Transact SQL I figured I'd throw that out there.  Also it doesn't look like "Name" is reserved. (see the link in my answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here we go.  Looks like brackets aren't supported.  Use double quotes instead.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174147(v=sql.110).aspx